# Call function from HTML table data tags

Tags: python, html, django, django-templates

following is my code:

```
def format_taxes(self):
    tax_list = self.data['tax_list']
    send_tax = ''

    for tax in tax_list:
        send_tax = send_tax + unicode('<tr class="subtotal">'''
                                      '<td class="field">${label}</td>'''
                                      '<td class="total">${amount}</td>'''
                                      '</tr>').format(**tax)

    return send_tax

def subtotals_as_table(self):
        return unicode(u'<table>'
                            '<tr class="subtotal">'
                                '<td class="field">Subtotal</td>'
                                '<td class="total">${subtotal}</td>'
                            '</tr>'
                            '''
                            **How do I call the format_taxes() function in here?**
                            '''
                            '<tr class="subtotal">'
                                '<td class="field">Total</td>'
                                '<td class="total">${total}</td>'
                            '</tr>'
                        '</table>'.format(**self.data))
```

Everything works great. It's just that I want to call format_taxes() function in the  tag data and I have no idea how to do that. Can anyone please help me out?

Comment: Why are you doing all this directly in Python? You've tagged this question as django-templates, but you aren't using Django templates at all. They are made for exactly this, and you should be using them.

Comment: @DanielRoseman: I'm still a newbie and still trying to learn things..

Comment: Yes, so you should learn how to do things properly. The Django tutorial shows you exactly how to use the template system: you should do that tutorial first.

Comment: Cool. Will do that. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't call a function inside a format string, but it's not hard to do it the right way.  Most likely what you want is something like:

```
def subtotals_as_table(self):
    format_args = self.data.copy()
    format_args['taxes'] = self.format_taxes()
    return '<tr>...</tr> ${taxes} <tr>...</tr>'.format(**format_args)
```

Answer (score -1):

To call within the HTML use the following:

< input id="clickMe" type="button" value="clickme" onclick="doFunction();" / >

Comment: It is not a js function the OP needs to call.

Comment: You really need to read questions more closely. None of your answers really address the questions.